# How can I require aws_sdk file in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, amazon-cloudsearch, joomla3.5

I am trying to require a CloudSearchDomainClient in my model but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:___\libraries\aws_sdk\Aws\CloudSearchDomain\CloudSearchDomainClient'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:___\components\com_sr\models\searchresults.php
>   on line 6

I tried using jimport, and even though it found the CloudSearchDomainClient it wasn't able to find the classes imported in CloudSearchDomainClient. Anyone had any similar issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, just `jimport('aws_sdk.aws-autoloader');` did the trick!